# Angular - Directive - onLoad - Element text

Tags: angularjs, directive

i have this code

```
  wall.directive('showMore2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope,$http) {

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function(event) {
                text = $(element).text();
                alert(text);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

so... when i click this element i get the text...
But i want... without click the element to get the content. When i remove the bind event and get element text.. i only get "`{{post.description}}`" which is before bind the data....

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this , take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/BmF27/

Comment: nope.... only with the click event works....

Comment: open your console and you'll see "Hello" there

Comment: <p show-more2>{{post.description}}</p>

it alerts "{{post.description}}"